# How can I make this code clearer so that a user can prompt from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, prompt

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    String filename = args[0];
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));//creates a scanner file object
    int rc = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
```

This is just a bit of my code, 
MatrixFind.jar c:\temp\infile.txt 10 59

This is what the user needs to prompt int he command line. I just would like to know is there anything I am doing wrong? and also, what is a better way to do this? Obviously there is more code, but the user just needs a filename path, a rows/columns number, and the number they are searching for. Not only that, whenever i try and do it in the comand prompt, it keeps saying unable to access jar file.

Comment: I think you should go though some java tutorials first. How to make a jar file, accepting command line args, etc.

Comment: Yeah I never realized I had to actually make the jar file, i thought it came packaged in. And my command prompt lines work, so i think this question is done o,o